# Explicit type is missing (int assumed)

Tags: c++, class, constructor, header

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. It's a really simple program I made to practice using headers, classes and constructors. It says that I'm not missing a return type for the function getValue() in Header2.cpp. I have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Header2.h"

int main()
{
    Thing Implement(1);
    std::cout << "The truth value is: " << Implement.getValue() << std::flush << "/n";

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Header2.h

```
#ifndef Object_H_
#define Object_H_

class Thing
{
public:
    Thing(int a);

int getValue();
private:
int truthValue;
};

#endif // Object_H_
```

Header2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header2.h"

Thing::Thing(int a)
{
if (a != 0 || a != 1)
{
    std::cout << "Improper truth value." << std::flush;
}
else
{
    truthValue = a;
}
};

Thing::getValue()
{
return truthValue;
};
```

Comment: Which is it, "Header.h" or "Header2.h"?

Comment: Header2.h and Header2.cpp. Sorry about that. I'll edit the main post to fix that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are missing an **int**

```
int Thing::getValue()
{
return truthValue;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Thing::getValue()
{
return truthValue;
};
```

Should be:

```
int Thing::getValue()
{
return truthValue;
};
```