# Trying to construct simple test class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding some errors I've been getting.  I have constructed a simple Test class with a driver.  Can somebody please point out the errors I have made?

Here I'm trying to create a Test object and set the number variable to 1, and then print the number variable.

driver:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Test *myTest = new Test(1);
    cout << myTest->getNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef __TEST_H__
#define __TEST_H__

class Test
{
private:
    int number;

public:
  Test();
  Test(int theNumber);
  int getNumber();
};

#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

Test() {
}

Test(int aNumber) {
    number = aNumber;
}

int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

The error I'm getting here is

```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "Test::getNumber()",
> referenced from:
>       _main in cc8cXu6w.o   "Test::Test(int)", referenced from:
>       _main in cc8cXu6w.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you

Comment: Define your function as int Test::getNumber()

Comment: Your implementations are *all* missing `Test::` before their identifiers in your .cpp file. I cannot see how that file even compiled, as `number` would have been flagged as an undefined variable (and perhaps that is another problem entirely, which you've yet-to-discover, that you're not even compiling `test.cpp` to begin with).

Comment: I tried that and I still get the error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Test::getNumber()", referenced from:
      _main in ccz21oeR.o
  "Test::Test(int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccz21oeR.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I don't believe you're even compiling+linking with `test.cpp`. If you were, it would fail to compile as-written. There is no variable `number` anywhere in that source file, and without class-scope-resolution `Test::` on the members in that file it certainly won't use `Test::number`. All it does is declare a stack of functions, two of which have assumed `int` return values (and your compiler should have [warned you about that as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897243/explicit-type-is-missing-int-assumed), but again, would *not* if `test.cpp` isn't being compiled in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is 64 bit? The code all looks good to me, depending on compiler? Looks good for mingw.

Comment: I thought I declared the variable number in the test.h file as a private variable?

Comment: How do I know if the compiler is 64 bit?

Comment: It is 64 bit, not that it has anything to do with this. `x86_64` in your architecture list is pretty telling what your target is. And *again*, post the *exact* output from your compilation that eventually leads to that error message. As I noted before, if test.cpp is *not* in the compilation list and `test.o` is not in the link list (if you have one separate). **you're not compiling test.cpp**, which I firmly believe is the case. If you were, your current source file without the class-scope resolution would result in a *failed* compilation of test.cpp and you wouldn't even make it to the link.

Comment: My bad. In test.cpp add "Test::" before each function as stated by WhozCraig, ie "Test::Test() {}" etc in the cpp file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use class scope when defining a class member outside its class.

```
Test::Test(){
}

Test::Test(int aNumber){
    //...
}

int Test::getNumber(){
    //...
}
```

Also, don't forget to compile and link test.cpp. Compiling only main.cpp (or whatever is your driver source file called) could also lead to such linking error.

If you use GCC, use the following command to build:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp test.cpp
```

Comment: I did this before: 
g++ -c test.cpp
g++ -c driver.cpp
gcc -o test.o driver.o
Which gave me errors.  I have tried it the way you suggested and it complies without errors.  Just doesn't print anything.

Comment: @CocaCola `gcc -o test.o`... that just overwrote the very file you just created with `g++ -c test.cpp`. That line should be `gcc -o test test.o driver.o` to generate a finish product called `test`. And regarding no output. `cout << myTest->getNumber() << '\n';` probably would' hurt, as `std::cout` is line-buffered. It should have printed anyway when the program shut down and stdout were flushed, however.

Comment: I compiled the same code and it prints "1" as it should. Did you actually run the resulting file after compilation?

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig... I thought it would create a.out if I didn't put a name there.  I'm doing this:
g++ -c test.cpp
g++ -c driver.cpp
g++ -o test driver.cpp test.cpp
test
and get nothing printed.

Comment: Compiling the program doesn't execute the code - only builds the executable file. You should run the "test" file after compilation to execute the code and get the output from your program.

Comment: Hmmm... I just did ./test!  I haven't used c++ for 2 yrs and have always been bad with linking.  Thank you so much everybody :)